# Please critique my Engine game

Tags: engines, analysis, programming

Two of my engine's played against Garbo engine. (without a opening Book on my part.) Both lost :( Which played better? I need a comparative analysis. Both shared the same evaluation. frankenstein played much faster :(

```
[Site "Chessrig app"]
[White "garbo"]
[Black "frankenstein"]
[Opening "Mieses-Kotroc Variation, Center Counter"]
[Event "Simmulation"]
[Date "2017-11-13"]
[TimeControl "unlimited"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Termination "Checkmate by white in 75 moves."]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Nc3 Qd4 4. Nf3 Qd6 5. d4 Bg4 6. h3 Bh5 7. g4 Bg6 8. Ne5 Qe6 9. Bb5+ c6 10. Bc4 Qd6 11. h4 e6 12. h5 Bxc2 13. Qxc2 Qxd4 14. Qe2 Qd6 15. Bf4 f6 16. Ng6 e5 17. Nxh8 Ne7 18. Bf7+ Kd7 19. Rd1 Nd5 20. Bxd5 exf4 21. Be4 Na6 22. Nf7 Qxd1+ 23. Qxd1+ Ke8 24. Nd6+ Kd8 25. Qb3 Bxd6 26. Qg8+ Kc7 27. Qxa8 Bb4 28. Bxh7 Nc5 29. Qxa7 f3 30. a3 Nd3+ 31. Bxd3 Bd6 32. Ba6 Kd7 33. Qxb7+ Bc7 34. Ne4 Kd8 35. Qc8+ Ke7 36. Qxc7+ Kf8 37. Qd8+ Kf7 38. Bc4# 1-0
```

[game1](http://www.chess.com/emboard?id=3708536) analysis using chess.com

```
[Site "Chessrig app"]
[White "garbo"]
[Black "prospect"]
[Opening "Mieses-Kotroc Variation, Center Counter"]
[Event "Simmulation"]
[Date "2017-11-13"]
[TimeControl "unlimited"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Termination "Checkmate by white in 59 moves."]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Nc3 Qd4 4. Nf3 Qd6 5. d4 Bg4 6. h3 Bh5 7. g4 Bg6 8. Ne5 Qe6 9. Bb5+ c6 10. Bc4 Qd6 11. h4 e6 12. h5 Bxc2 13. Qxc2 Qxd4 14. Qe2 Qd6 15. Bf4 f6 16. Ng6 e5 17. Nxh8 Ne7 18. Bf7+ Kd7 19. Rd1 Nd5 20. Bxd5 exf4 21. Be4 Na6 22. Nf7 Qxd1+ 23. Qxd1+ Kc7 24. Qf3 Re8 25. Qxf4+ Kc8 26. Kd2 Re6 27. Bf5 Nc7 28. Re1 g5 29. Rxe6 gxf4 30. Re8# 1-0
```

[game2](http:////www.chess.com/emboard?id=3708538) analysis using chess.com

Comment: Can you please fix the layout?

Comment: Both your engines love to play the queen to much in the opening. Probably you should value development more in their evaluation function...

Comment: Tried to fix the layout but couldn’t figure it out? Any tips?

Comment: fixed the layout. looks like [FEN ""] is mandatory for the widget to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by asking why your engine is making horrible tempo loss moves with the queen?  8...Qe6? in game one and 3...Qd4? in game two.  You need to consider "developing with tempo" somehow.

Comment: Both games are actually identical until move 10, when it is dead lost for Black...

Comment: @Evargalo You mean 23.

Comment: @Annatar oh yes. I didn't bother to look further...

Comment: @Evargalo Your assessment is still true though. It makes no sense to compare these engines against each other if they both fail in the exact same way.

Answer (score 4):

- It was obviously a fast game, and your search depth was too **low**. Your engine liked moving the queen because it didn't see it'd be driven back a few moves later.
- You need to define better piece square values table. If you do it properly, the engine should aim to control the center with a pawn or a piece, but not moving the queen out.